# The data in linked list won't show on the Text Area in GUI. Java. Why?

Tags: java, linked-list, iterator

I am currently doing a book inventory system in linked list using Java GUI. I have to add book information into a Node in linked list and display it by implementing the iterator.

I have done with my code and it shows no error. However, when I run the GUI and successfully add a book into the linked list then press the display button. It did not show the information I just added to the text area.

Did anywhere of my code have problem?

This is my Node class:

```
public class Node 
{
    Data data;
    Node next;

    public Node()
    {
        next = null;
    }

    Node(Data data, Node next)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public Object getData()
    {
        return data;
    }

    public Node getNext()
    {
        return next;   
    }

    public void setNext(Node next)
    {
        this.next=next;
   }
}
```

And this is my LinkedList class with the insertion and display method:

```
public class LinkedList
{
    Node node = new Node();
    static Data data;
    static Node head;

    public LinkedList()
    {
        head=null;
    }

    public Node getHead()
    {
        return head;
    }

    public static void addNode(Data data)
    {
        Node newNode = new Node(data, head);
        Node previous = null;
        Node current = head;

        while(current != null && data.name.compareTo(current.data.name) >= 0){
            previous = current;
            current = current.next;
        }

        if(previous == null){
            head = newNode;
        }else{
            previous.next = newNode;
        }
            newNode.next = null;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Book Information has been added to the inventory.");
    }
}

    public static String displayNode()
    {
        DisplayIterator i;
        Node current = head;
        String output = "";       
        while(DisplayIterator.hasNext())
        {
            output+= DisplayIterator.next();
            current=current.next;
        }      
        return output+"NULL";
    }
```

This is my data class which I used to store all the information into one Node:

```
public class Data {
    String name;
    String author;
    int isbn;
    int number;
    String genre;
    Node head;

    public Data(String name, String author, int isbn, int number, String genre)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.author = author;
        this.isbn = isbn;
        this.number = number;
        this.genre = genre;
    }

    public String toString(String name, String author, int isbn, int number, String genre)
    {
        return("Book Name: "+name+"\nAuthor: "+author+"\nISBN Number: "+isbn+"\nNumber of Copies: "+number+"\nGenre: "+genre+"\n");
    }
}
```

And lastly this is my Iterator class:

```
public class DisplayIterator
{
    Data data;
    static Node current;

    DisplayIterator(Data data)
    {       
        this.data = data;
        current = data.head;    
    }

    public static boolean hasNext()
    {
        if(current != null){            
            return true;
        }       
        return false;       
    }

    public static Object next()
    {
        if(hasNext()){
        current = current.getNext();
        return current.getData().toString();            
    }       
        return null;        
    }

    public void remove()
    {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("It is read-only.");        
    }       
}
```

I think the problem is on the DisplayIterator class but I can't see where. 
Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: Why are you using your own `LinkedList` and iterator classes instead of those already in the JDK? And did you debug your code? Besides that you seem to have problems with displaying the new element in some text area but you didn't provide any details on how you add the element and how you update the text area.

Comment: Where do you instantiate `DisplayIterator` ?  Also, its methods shouldn't be static .

Comment: @Thomas This is what the exercise asked for, use my own linked list then implement the iterator to display it. The add method was in the Linked List class and I was adding it through GUI, click the add button then it will call the LinkedList.addNode method. And yes I have debug the code but nothing comes out.

Comment: @Berger It was in the LinkedList class, the displayNode method.

Comment: You never instantiate it, i.e you never call its constructor.

Comment: @Berger I see... I will try that, thanks !!

Comment: If it's an exercise you should mention it since we'll then be able to better understand your problem domain and skills. Besides that, if you just add something to a list the textarea won't be updated unless you invalidate it. Either add a listener to check for changes in the list or manually invalidate/repaint the textarea after adding the element to the list.

Comment: @Thomas  I have a button to display the list. In the button I wrote this `LinkedList list; jTextArea1.setText(LinkedList.displayNode())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data.head is always null

```
DisplayIterator(Data data)
{       
    this.data = data;
    current = data.head;  // this will always make current as null.  
}
```

In your following class , the constructor does not initialize your head node.

```
public class Data {
   String name;
   String author;
   int isbn;
   int number;
   String genre;
   Node head; // not set any where?
```

Also your addNode is not correct.

```
public static void addNode(Data data)
{
    Node newNode = new Node(data, head);
    Node previous = null;
    Node current = head; //this will be always NULL on first addNode call

    while(current != null && data.name.compareTo(current.data.name) >= 0){
        previous = current;
        current = current.next;
    }

    if(previous == null){
        head = newNode;
    }else{
        previous.next = newNode;
    }
        newNode.next = current; // how can be newNode.next is current?
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Book Information has been added to the inventory.");
}
```

Comment: Oh, the head was supposed to be the first Node in the linked list. It was set under the addNode class. So I wasn't supposed to set the head as the current in my DisplayIterator class ?

Comment: @Acetamide your addNode needs some refactoring i suppose.

Comment: Oh! I think I made a mistake, the `newNode.next` supposed to be like this `newNode.next = head;`, is this right ?

Comment: @Acetamide in reality newNode.next should be always NULL in my opinion as nothing is next to it yet!

Comment: Oh right, got it. Because in my previous exercise we learn to put that in newNode.next though. Updated to the question already. Also, in the DisplayIterator class, the `current = data.head` is the problem why I can't get the list show in the text area ?

Comment: @Acetamide seems to be, please accept my answer if it helped you to fill loop holes :)

Comment: Of course ^^ But if `current.data.head` wasn't the one I supposed to write, then what Node should I have the current pointing to? It supposed to be the first Node in the linked list I think.

Comment: I change the `Node head` in my Data class to `Node head = LinkedList.getHead()` as there is a method in my LinkedList class to return the first Node in the list. But it still gives me the NullPointer error.